# I failed to call component's method inside of vue-froala-wysiwyg event

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, froala

in  laravel 8/2.6/bootstrap 4.6/Axios app using vue-froala-wysiwyg  I need to get content of entered text and
call component's method with entered text.
I define event as I read here https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg :

```
import VueFroala from 'vue-froala-wysiwyg' // https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs
Vue.use(VueFroala) // https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// let self = this

export default {
    name: "RoomChat",
    components: {},

    data() {
        return {
            currentRoom: null,
            ...
            froalaEditorConfig: {
                events: {
                    initialized: function () {
                        console.log('froalaEditorConfig initialized')
                    },

                    'contentChanged': function () {    // https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events/
                        console.log('froalaEditorConfig contentChanged this::')
                        // this - is reference to froala component
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log('this.el::')
                        // I tryied to get ref to root component in several ways
                        console.log(this.el)  // undefined
                        console.log('this.el.$parent::')
                        console.log(this.el.$parent)  // undefined
                        console.log('this.$parent::')
                        console.log(this.$parent)  // undefined

                        console.log('froalaEditorConfig contentChanged this.html.get()::')
                        console.log(this.html.get());
                        parent.actionUser(this.html.get()) // I got parent.actionUser is not a function error
                    }, 

                },
            },
  
    ...
   
    methods: {
        actionUser(enteredText) {
        ...
```

Which way is valid?

**ADDED :**
Searching for decision I found
https://medium.com/dataseries/vue-js-components-parent-child-and-root-f1fcbe422feb
article with this.$root described but making inside of my event :

```
console.log('this.$root::')
console.log(this.$root)
```

Undefined is outputted.

What I see inside of event outputting this : https://prnt.sc/1r6pp4y and https://prnt.sc/1r6ptoh

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found decision with sending vueComponent instance as parameter :

```
    data:(vm) => ({
            ...
            froalaEditorConfig: {
                events: {
                    initialized: function () {
                    },

                    contentChanged () {
                        vm.actionUser(this.html.get()) // That works ok
                    }, 

                },
                ....
            },
   }), // data(vm) => ({
```

Comment: After struggling whole day, I found your solution. Thanks a lot.